# ASP.NET SQL Query One of Many Columns Undefined

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

**General Description:** Single SQL query of multiple SQL databases (through joins) returns all but one item from all but one database.  Item not being returned is joined via an item that can, and sometimes is, null.

**Specific Description:**
I am continuing development of an internal ticketing system for work.  I just started with C#, SQL and web development about a month ago, so I am still wrapping my head around all of the interconnections and syntax of Jquery, SQL, C#, and MVC.

Currently I am trying to display an SQL query in a table to show brief information for our tickets to support members.  I have everything being displayed except "CircuitDescription" which is a pretty important element in order for support to differentiate between circuits.  It is coming through on the table as "undefined" which I have gathered is the JQuery response for an initialized variable. All other values are coming through on the web page.

Running the SQL query through Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio displays the column with the circuit description.

**Disclaimer:**
While searching for this I have seen posts discouraging multiple database queries, but this is how the program was written before so I want to keep my code as similar to what has been done so far as possible.
So if we could jump past the part where it is implied I am an idiot (as is my only experience asking questions on stackoverflow) that would be lovely.
If you help me solve this, and help me learn why what you suggest works, then you can feel free to imply or directly call me anything you like.

**Code:**

C# / SQL Query:

-The join statements are combining the lists by a numeric value from DB "Tickets" with a numeric value from the other databases.  Those databases are holding 2 columns, the numeric value and a corresponding string description.

-The full outer join is combining the list by a numeric circuitID from the tickets to a numeric circuitID in the circuits database.

-The circuit database holds the circuit description I am struggling with.

-Some circuitID values are null, which I suspect may be why this is not working.  The other join statements that I am receiving data in connection to are all not null.

```
public static async Task<List<Ticket>> GetAllTicketsForCustomerAsync(DBAccess db, int customerID)
    {
        var cmd = "select TicketID, Tickets.DateCreated, Tickets.DateResolved, Tickets.CustomerCircuitID, CircuitDescription, TicketTypeDesc, BillingStatusDescription, TicketStatusDescription " +
            "from Tickets " +
            "join TicketTypes on Tickets.TicketTypeID = TicketTypes.TicketTypeID " +
            "join TicketStatusTypes on Tickets.TicketStatus = TicketStatusTypes.TicketStatus " +
            "join TicketBillingStatusTypes on Tickets.BillingStatus = TicketBillingStatusTypes.BillingStatus " +
            "full outer join CustomerCircuits on Tickets.CustomerCircuitID = CustomerCircuits.CustomerCircuitID " +
            "where Tickets.CustomerID = " + customerID +
            "order by Tickets.TicketID DESC";
        var table = await db.ReadTableAsync(cmd);
        return (from DataRow row in table.Rows select db.AssignFromRow<Ticket>(row)).ToList();
    }
```

JQuery:

-Ternary operator for circDesc is to list any tickets without a circuitID as "NonSpecific" for their circuit description. Otherwise they should display the circuit description that is currently coming through as "Undefined"

```
function buildPartialCustomerTicketsTable(tickets) {
var table = "";

var maxSize = (tickets.length < 5) ? tickets.length : 5;


for (var i = 0; i < maxSize; i++) {
    var t = tickets[i];        

    var circDesc = (t.CustomerCircuitID == null) ? "Nonspecific" : t.CircuitDescription;

    var rowClass = ((i % 2) == 0) ? "listRowNormal" : "listRowAlternate";
    table += "<tr class='" + rowClass + "'>"
    + "<td class='listElement'><a href='#' onclick='viewTicket(" + t.TicketID + ",true)'>update</a></td>"
    + "<td class='listElement'>" + t.TicketStatusDescription + "</td>"
    + "<td class='listElement'>" + formatDate(t.DateCreated) + "</td>"
    + "<td class='listElement'>" + formatDate(t.DateResolved) + "</td>"
    + "<td class='listElement'>" + circDesc + "</td>"
    + "<td class='listElement'>" + t.TicketTypeDescription + "</td>"
    + "<td class='listElement'>" + t.BillingStatusDescription + "</td>"
    + "<td class='listElement'>" + t.TicketID + "</td>"
    + "</tr>";
}

return table;
```

}

**Requested Code:**

```
    public T AssignFromRow<T>(DataRow row) where T : new()
{
    var rec = new T();
    this.AssignFromRow(row, rec);
    return rec;
}



    public void AssignFromRow(DataRow row, object rec)
{
    if (row == null || rec == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Look at all of the properties in the record
    PropertyInfo[] recprops = rec.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo pi in recprops)
    {
        // default the sql column name to the property name
        string columnName = pi.Name;

        // skip any read only parameters
        if (!pi.CanWrite)
        {
            continue;
        }

        // Check for a mapping attribute. This attribute can change the name of the table column name from the default.
        var customAttrs = pi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MappingAttribute), false);
        if (customAttrs.Length > 0)
        {
            var mapping = (MappingAttribute)customAttrs[0];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mapping.ColumnName))
            {
                columnName = mapping.ColumnName;
            }
        }

        // If the row does not have this element name then skip it
        if (!row.Table.Columns.Contains(columnName))
        {
            continue;
        }

        // If the DataRow has a value with the same name, and it is not null, then assign it
        object dbval = row[columnName];
        if (dbval != null && !(dbval is DBNull))
        {
            pi.SetValue(rec, dbval, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your query is not from multiple databases, but rather from multiple Tables and or views? (which could be from another database) . There is nothing inherently wrong with that.

If the query runs fine in SSMS then The problem is more than likely in your subsequent (jquery code)

You have to learn how to use break points in your code and find out where the code is being 'undefined'

Comment: Still getting used to visual studio 2015 and web development.  The breakpoints are not intuitive for me in this environment.

But this doesn't seem like breakpoints would be super helpful.  JQuery does not see a value, and the SQL query works fine.  Some data is handed off to jquery but not this one specific value. So it seems the error must be in C# particularly the connection betwen C# and SQL.
Unless you have different insight on breakpoints for me?

Comment: As for the "multiple databases" I was thinking of each file as its own database but I suppose that each file is a view/table?
As I said, very new to all of this so the terminology is not there yet.  The posts I read calling it multiple databases seemed to be what you refer to as multiple tables and views.
I will continue searching using the criteria multiple tables/views rather than multiple databases while I await further reply. Thanks for the terminology qualification.

Comment: In your particular case your C# code is all or nothing. meaning that if you are getting some data then the C# code is working. You said that the SQL checks out fine, so that is not the problem. The only thing left is the jquery code you show. If you cant put break points in your jquery then use alert. as in: alert(t.CircuitDescription)

Comment: Alerts I have done, for each value of the select statement. From success of the ajax get statement and from the function called on success.  Both show undefined for this one value.  
Maybe I don't understand how the connections are made but it seems like if the ajax call succeeds but no value is in circuit description then it means nothing was sent to it from C#.

Comment: If you change this var circDesc = (t.CustomerCircuitID == null) ... to this: circDesc =  (!t.CircuitDescription) are ALL of the descriptions undefined?

Comment: Does you model, Ticket, have the field CircuitDescription in it?

Comment: @ChadMcGrath Yes they are.  I changed it to this to show at least some function.

Also, if I omit the ternary all together and use t.CircuitDescription rather than circDesc in the table, everything is undefined.

Comment: @ScottMacMaster CircuitDescription is unique to the CustomerCircuits table.  The shared value between them is CustomerCircuitID

Comment: I think @ScottMacMaster is suggesting that you may be missing it from the Ticket object, or somehow omitted before it's sent to the client, but after you get it in the query. Does that make sense? Is that a possibility?

Comment: Well, the code 'select db.AssignFromRow<Ticket>(row)' indicates to me it's only returning fields from the Ticket table.  If CircuitDescription is in CustomerCircuits then you'll have to modify that.  If Ticket is generated from a database then the simplest approach would be to create a view in the database and query that.

Comment: I thought that as well but TicketTypeDesc, BillingStatusDescription, TicketStatusDescription are not in Ticket but return the expected description strings.  They are in independent tables as well. Perhaps I explained that poorly.  Each of those tables are a numeric value and a string.  The numeric values are held in Tickets but the description is held in their own tables (named as implied by the join statements).

Comment: I think this may be getting diverted off track. JGB you have said your SQL is fine. Put a break point before table and see what is being returned. 
Also, show us how Ticket is defined.

Comment: @DaniDev I'll tinker with the breakpoint now.  What do you mean by how ticket is defined? Do you mean the what items are in ticket?

Comment: if you post this method in your question : db.AssignFromRow<Ticket>(row) that's in your DBAccess class. We'll be able to tell you. It the Ticket object we're interested in, rahter than the Ticket table, and the method that assigns your database results to it.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k80ex6de%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I assume your using Visual Studio.  Right click on Ticket and select 'go to definition'.  From there you'll be able to see if CircuitDescription is a field in the Ticket object or not.

Comment: Ahh yes I got it.  It is not there.  I apparently had not dug that deep.

Comment: My Model knowledge is not up to par as I have not written my own yet outside of the MVC tutorial.  This is not something I can simply add in, correct?

Comment: Oh I can.  It's working now. Thank you so much for the help!
@ScottMacMaster